# ExtJS 4.1.1 Infinite Scrolling only loading first page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, infinite-scroll

I want to get an infinite scrolling grid with extjs4 and a c# backend... i am setting the proxy api in my controller..

My Model:

```
Ext.define('appname.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'ID',
    fields: [
        { name: 'ID', type: 'int', convert: null },
        { name: 'EmployeeName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Description', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'StatusText', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Status', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Priority', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Date', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Cost', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'CanApprove', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'CanRequest', type: 'bool' },
        { name: 'ConfirmStatus', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PlanId', type: 'int'}
    ]

});
```

My Grid:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    flex: 1,
    padding: '0 10 10 10',
    minHeight: 200,
    verticalScroller: {
        xtype: 'paginggridscroller'
    },
    store: {
        model: 'appname.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList',
        pageSize: 200,
        autoLoad: true,
        buffered: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        sorters: {
            property: 'Date',
            direction: 'DESC'
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            extraParams: {
                total: 50000
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'ID',
                totalProperty: 'TotalCount'
            },
            simpleSortMode: true
        }
    },
    columns:
        [{
            text: Lang.Main.Employeee,
            dataIndex: 'EmployeeName',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Course,
            dataIndex: 'Description',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Status,
            dataIndex: 'StatusText',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Priority,
            dataIndex: 'Priority',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Date,
            dataIndex: 'Date',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Cost,
            dataIndex: 'Cost',
            flex: 1,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            text: Lang.Main.Actions,
            flex: 1,
            align: 'center',
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 50,
            items: [{
                icon: 'Design/icons/cog_edit.png',
                tooltip: Lang.Main.Open,
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item) {
                    this.onGridOpen(grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex));
                }
            }]
        }],      
    selModel: { mode: 'MULTI', selType: 'checkboxmodel' },
}
```

setting proxy in controoler:

```
view.grid.getStore().setProxy({
            type: 'direct', 
            model: 'appname.model.training.course.TrainingRequirementList', 
            api: { read: SCT.Service.Training.Plan.GetFilteredRequirements }, 
            extraParams: { total: 50000 }, 
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'ID',
                totalProperty: 'TotalCount'
            },
            simpleSortMode: true
        });
```

additional information about my view:

```
Ext.define('appname.view.training.course.TrainingRequirements',
    {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        require: [ 'Ext.grid.PagingScroller'],
```

My grid is only loading the first 200 rows and the scrollbar is only as big as it would be for 200 rows.. :/ ...

the server response with entries like this:

```
{"ID":99,"PlanId":23,"firstname":"name","lastname":"name","Comment":"","Status":3,"ConfirmType":0,"Priority":"entry","DesiredDate":null,"StartDate":new Date(1354107600000),"ActualCost":180,"EstimatedCost":0,"row":201,"TotalCount":8568,"EmployeeName":"some, name","Description":"","StatusText":"state","Date":"28.11.2012","Cost":"EUR 180"}
```

what am i missing???

**UPDATE**

When i scroll down the script is loading the second page also.. still nothing more...

if you ned more information dont hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your server include the correct `TotalCount` value in the response?

Edit:

According to your reader's configuration, your server should answer with data formatted this way (of course your response should also be valid JSON, here Javascript is used for illustration):

```
{
    // total property at the root level of response object
    TotalCount: 8568,

    // root for items data, configured as "ID" in your reader (you should probably
    // change that to something like "records" or "data" to better express meaning)
    ID: [
        // individual fields data
        {ID: 1, EmployeeName: 'Foo', ...},
        {ID: 2, EmployeeName: 'Bar', ...},
        ...
    ]

    // if you had, for example, a successProperty, it would go here too
    ,success: true
}
```

In your case, it seems that your `TotalCount` is mixed in every item data?

You're right about the implementation on the server side: it should simply be the total number of records, so something like `COUNT(*)` in the database.

One more thing: `new Date(1354107600000)` is not valid JSON. You should use a string and cast it to a date once the JSON has been decoded. For example, in your model, your could configure the field type to have Ext handle this for your: `{name: 'Date', type: 'date', format: 'd.m.Y'}`.

Comment: as you can see the `TotalCount` response is 8568 which is the correct number.

Comment: my TotalCount is just a count over all rows in sql like this:  `Count(*) OVER() as TotalCount` am i doing this the correct way?

Comment: i just saw he is loading also the second page when i scroll down.. but still not all entries.. :/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it because I assumed the data you were showing was for only one record. Your response format seems to have some problems. I'm updating my answer to explain.

Comment: thank you very much. it seems i didnt understand how the dataset has to look like. i'll give this a try and reply you afterwards